# project() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'

Tags: django

am confuse right now...i want to pass in a key value but i kept on getting error

my code urls

```
from django.urls import URLPattern, path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.projects, name="projects"),
    path('project/', views.project, name="project"),
]
```

and the function i created

```
def project(request, pk):
    projectObj = None
    for i in projectslist:
        if i['id'] == pk:
            projectObj = i
    return render(request, 'projects/single-project.html', {'project': projectObj})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the pk argument in your url.

```
path('project/<int:pk>/', views.project, name="project"),
```

Related docs. [URLS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#:%7E:text=Error%20handling%20below.-,Example,-%C2%B6), [Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial03/#:%7E:text=for%20more%20information.-,Writing%20more%20views,-%C2%B6)

Comment: thanks for that help i really appreciate and to my greatest surprise it worked....thanks once again